# mongodb 3rd node replica set crashes

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 node replica set setup . However my third node keeps crashing while syncing . i have tried seperate systems but the third node always ends up crashing. here are the logs

```
Wed Jun 19 01:27:38.514 [rsSync] Socket recv() timeout  109.123.100.239:27017
Wed Jun 19 01:27:38.514 [rsSync] SocketException: remote: 109.123.100.239:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [3] server [109.123.100.239:27017] 
Wed Jun 19 01:27:38.514 [rsSync] DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Jun 19 01:27:38.524 [rsSync] replSet initial sync exception: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: transport error: twitnot.es:27017 ns: local.oplog.rs query: { query: {}, orderby: { $natural: -1 } } 9 attempts remaining
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is perform a "cold backup"

You have 3 nodes

primary

secondady

crashed

Steps:

1. Conect to crashed one
2. go to /data/ folder and clean all files but mongo.lock and journal
   folder
3. Stop mongod on the secondary
4. copy all files from /data/ folder from secondary to crashed one. Do 
   not copy journal folder, mongo.lock
5. start mongod on secondary node
6. configure 'mongod' ownership for the updated files and 600 permissions
7. cross your finguers
8. start mongod on crashed one